# Get variable from another callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, callback

I'm using Jquery File Upload plugin. How can I get the **category_id** varibale (in **processstop** callback function) and passing it into **done** callback function.

```
jupload.fileupload({
    url: 'upload.php',
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
    maxFileSize: 1536000,
    autoUpload: true,
    processfail: function(e, data){
        alert(data.files[data.index].error);
    },
    processstop: function (e, data) {
        // Create a category
        $.post('add_category.php',{'thumbnail':''},function(data) {
            var json = data,
                obj = JSON && JSON.parse(json) || $.parseJSON(json);

            // CATEGORY ID
            var category_id = obj.id;
        });
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
        // HOW CAN I GET THE `category_id` ABOVE TO USING ADD PRODUCT?

        // Add products to category
        $.post('product_add.php',{'category_id':category_id},function(data) {
            /* ...... */
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to define category_id above your jquery file uploader initializer.

```
var category_id;
jupload.fileupload({
...
});
```